# Is there a way to know who is the sender of "setNeedsDisplay"?

Tags: ios, uiview, uipickerview

I have a few UIpickerView's that sends `setNeedsDisplay` to their parent view.
Is there any way to get the identity of the sender ?

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for you to get the sender of that method. There are a couple important things to note here:  first, you shouldn't be overriding `setNeedsDisplay` *at all*, you should override `drawRect:` which will be called if the view needs to be redrawn. Second, I would suggest you use `UIPickerView`'s delegate property, set it your parent view, and then do any processing you need to do in the `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`  delegate method.

Comment: Hi. thanks for you answer. isn't setNeedsDisplay ment for telling the receiver to call drawrect:?

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't say not to *call* it, I said not to *override* it.